# How to build a Snappy Ubuntu Core for a new arm board?

Tags: ubuntu-core

Accessing the office url [boadr-enablement](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/guides/build-device/board-enablement),I can success building a kernel.snap for amd64. But when I build a kernel.snap for my arm board ,there are some error . eg: `kernel build did not output a vmlinux binary in top level dir, expected '/kernel_yuan/parts/kernel/build/arch/x86/boot/zImage'`

question:i build for arm ,but there appear x86 ，for what ?

how i can build a kernel snap for my board ?

can you offer a link for arm board building when you compile the url project success.

Comment: I have solved. before i compile the project using   ` snapcraft --target-arch armhf  snap`,now i compile it using `snapcraft --target-arch armhf`. And I does not konw why .